# Is there a search tool to filter posts that have been edited?

Tags: support, feature-request, search

I recently discovered how to filter for posts with a range of scores in the search bar: `score:1...5` and `score:-100..-1`. I noticed that this feature is not displayed in the *Advanced Search Tips* cheat sheet in the search bar.

Is there a way to filter posts that have been edited?

I think it may be under Status, but I'm not sure:

```
Status:
  - closed:yes
  - duplicate:no
  - migrated:no
  - wiki:no
  - edited:no (?)
```

If not, maybe this could be a feature request. It'd be great for editors to search for non-edited questions to review.

Examples: `edited:no` `edits:0` `edits:1` `edits:5...7` `editedByNonOp:yes` `uniqueUsersEdited:5` `titleEdited:no` `tagsEdited:yes` `bodyEdited:no`

Comment: `revisions` would be a better name for the count and range search.

Comment: Hm. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=views%3A-2..-1) should not come up with a result.. Negative view range. `Results found Search options views -2 - -1`

Comment: I don't think this is possible with search. An alternative might be a [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1261482) if you accept that data can be up to a week old.

Answer (score 1):

Search Boolean operators are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching). There is no `edited` or `revisions` Boolean option so it would be good to perhaps do a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) on Meta Stack Exchange.

As rene mentioned, this can be done with a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1261482). Note: SEDE is updated every Sunday morning so the results could be a week old.